# select2 angular2+ setting 1st value as default

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angular2-directives

```
<select class="example-full-width js-example-basic-single" #country name="country" [(ngModel)]="companycountryValue" required>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countrydata" [value]="country.name">{{ country.value }}</option>
</select>
```

How can I make the 1st option as selected as the default option?
[(ngModel)]="companycountryValue" already has selected data too tried many methods none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In component just do

```
this.companycountryValue="some default country.name value"
```

just be adviced that default value muest be assignable to whatever is hiding under `country.name` so option  with this `[value]` will become selected

BONUS:
Didnt you want to do this ?

```
 <option *ngFor="let country of countrydata" [value]="country.value">{{ country.name}}</option>
```

Comment: The same option is present in list also.

Comment: stackblitz then. I think you are not setting the same value as her [value]="country.name". Those has to match. Moreover, I think that you wanted to print {contry.name} and set {contry.value} as value, not the other way around (like you did)

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bharighat consider upvote and accept my answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: Sure it really helped Thank you. but when I upvote I get an alert "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve the solution to your Problem

> Step1: // picking up the index of the option and setting it in html
>   attributes like this:

```
    <select class="example-full-width js-example-basic-single" #country name="country" [(ngModel)]="companycountryValue" required>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countrydata; let i = index" [value]="country.name" [selected]="i == 0 ? true : null" >{{ country.value }}</option>
</select>
```

> Step2: Setting up from the component to the select

```
ngOnit(){
          this.companycountryValue=countrydata[0];
}
```

and in html you can set like

```
<select class="example-full-width js-example-basic-single" #country name="country" [(ngModel)]="companycountryValue" required>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countrydata" [value]="country.name">{{ country.value }}</option>
</select>
```